# IBM Worklight - JMS Adapter to send message to TIBCO EMS

Tags: jms, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm working for BIDV, a big customer of IBM in Vietnam.

I'm developing a JMS Adapter to send message to TIBCO EMS. When I invoke procedure in Eclipse, this error occurs:

> Class com.worklight.adapters.jms.JMSConnectionManager$JMSSession can
>   not access a member of class com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp with
>   modifiers "public".

Can anyone help please?

Full log is below:

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure 
>   [project BIDVMobile]JMSTransfer/JMSProducerFWLSE0100E:  parameters:
>   [project BIDVMobile] Failed to create message
>   :java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
>   com.worklight.adapters.jms.JMSConnectionManager$JMSSession can not
>   access a member of class com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp with
>   modifiers "public" FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project
>   BIDVMobile]nulljava.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create message
>   :java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
>   com.worklight.adapters.jms.JMSConnectionManager$JMSSession can not
>   access a member of class com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp with
>   modifiers "public"    at
>   com.worklight.adapters.jms.JMSConnectionManager$JMSSession.createMessage(JMSConnectionManager.java:476)
>     at
>   com.worklight.adapters.jms.JMSSynchronousProducer.putMessage(JMSSynchronousProducer.java:54)
>     at
>   com.worklight.adapters.jms.JMSSynchronousProducer.invoke(JMSSynchronousProducer.java:49)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:57)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:169)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:38)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext$DirectExecutorService.execute(InvocationContext.java:284)
>     at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.submit(InvocationContext.java:138)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContextManager.submitInvocation(InvocationContextManager.java:58)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.callProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:497)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.access$100(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:56)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl$4.execute(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:392)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeProcedureInternal(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:456)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.invokeDynamicProcedure(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:432)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.invokeDynamicProcedure(JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation.java:126)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_24._c_anonymous_23(/integration.js:248)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.gen._integration_js_24.call(/integration.js)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.gen.H_3A_5Ckhanhpt_worklight_space2_5CBIDVMobile_5Cadapters_5CJMSTransfer_JMSTransfer_impl_js_29._c_writeMessage_1(H%3A%5Ckhanhpt_worklight_space2%5CBIDVMobile%5Cadapters%5CJMSTransfer/JMSTransfer-impl.js:15)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.gen.H_3A_5Ckhanhpt_worklight_space2_5CBIDVMobile_5Cadapters_5CJMSTransfer_JMSTransfer_impl_js_29.call(H%3A%5Ckhanhpt_worklight_space2%5CBIDVMobile%5Cadapters%5CJMSTransfer/JMSTransfer-impl.js)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.gen.H_3A_5Ckhanhpt_worklight_space2_5CBIDVMobile_5Cadapters_5CJMSTransfer_JMSTransfer_impl_js_29.call(H%3A%5Ckhanhpt_worklight_space2%5CBIDVMobile%5Cadapters%5CJMSTransfer/JMSTransfer-impl.js)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.callFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:240)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:214)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:194)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.invokeFunction(AdapterManagerImpl.java:104)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.invoke(JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.java:42)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:57)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:166)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:169)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:38)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.worklight.server.util.ProjectLocal$1RunnableWrapper.run(ProjectLocal.java:267)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that in Tibco EMS the JMS Session implementation class expose the method:
createTextMessage(...) as a protected or private.
Worklight is using Java reflection to create and send the message .
it calls several methods such as:
createTextMessage, setJMSReplyTo , setJMSCorrelationID and others...
can you attach the Tibco EMS client Jar  ?

Comment: I follow examples on IBM getting started page. I use an adapter configuration file and a javscript file to call WL.Server functions. Here are links my files:tibjms.jar
http://www.mediafire.com/download/movq2srtm93e385/tibjms.jar

JMSTransfer-impl.js
http://www.mediafire.com/view/zv5jexzo8abwvdw/JMSTransfer-impl.js

JMSTransfer.xml
http://www.mediafire.com/view/rxsssxc0hvhilmr/JMSTransfer.xml

server.xml
http://www.mediafire.com/view/w8zage4ogp0n96k/server.xml

Answer (score 1):

Can you show how you connect to TIBCO EMS?
Is that by code or by configuration?

As you mention you work for BIDV i might point you to the right persons locally next ;)

Cheers
       Seb

Comment: I follow examples on your getting started page. I use an adapter configuration file and a javscript file to call WL.Server functions. Here are links my files:tibjms.jar
http://www.mediafire.com/download/movq2srtm93e385/tibjms.jar

JMSTransfer-impl.js
http://www.mediafire.com/view/zv5jexzo8abwvdw/JMSTransfer-impl.js

JMSTransfer.xml
http://www.mediafire.com/view/rxsssxc0hvhilmr/JMSTransfer.xml

server.xml
http://www.mediafire.com/view/w8zage4ogp0n96k/server.xml

Comment: The config so far looks reasonable to me.  This looks more like a product then config error to me as worklight seems trying to access a non public part of the TIBCO Session Implementation via reflection (can not access a member of class com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp with modifiers "public").

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem, Worklight server running on WAS, JMS resources configured on WAS and pointing to WebSphere MQ. We solved the problem by adding a Service Integration Bus and Queues on WAS, so that the messages first go on a queue on the WAS SIB, then from there to MQ.